# meta queries do 'either/or' checks

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a meta_query like this , but 'relation' => 'OR'  NOT WORKING,
Does meta_query only do 'both/and' checks and  don't do 'either/or' ?

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'app_os',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',  
        'value' => 'iPhone',  
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'app_os',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',  
        'value' => 'iPad',  
    )
)
```

);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

meta_query works on 'both/and' checks and also 'either/or'.so don't worry.your coding was correct.this is the actual format...

```
$a = new WP_Query(
array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'foo',
            'value' => array( 'foobar' ),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'bar',
            'value' => array( 'foobar2' ),
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    )
) );
print_r( $a->posts );
```

---

you should try with this coding...

```
    $args=new WP_Query(
     array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'app_os',
            'value' => array('iPhone'),  
            'compare' => 'LIKE',  
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'app_os_2',
            'value' => array('iPad') ,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',  

        )
    )
    ); 
print_r($args->posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Relation for meta queries is not available in current stable version. It should be supported in soon to be released version 3.2

See [Introduce 'relation' arg to meta_query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17011) ticket on trac.